# Formatting an unused system drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, formatting

I have two system drives on my laptop. The drive that I am currently using is "C" drive which is working fine. I have another system drive called "D" which was used earlier by me, but now it is corrupted.

I want to format the "D" drive, and I have tried using the **Format** option, but it's saying that "You can't format this volume". Is there any way I can format it without using any external device or CD (in Windows 7 or Windows XP)?

Comment: Try any bootable Linux distro, for example burn a Ubuntu disk/create bootable USB drive.

Comment: Why the partition is corrupted might be important here - if its due to some serious functional issues, you might be better off replacing it

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove D partition in Computer management > Disk Management then create new empty disk and then format it.